# DX11 sprite troubles

Tags: c++, directx, 2d, sprite, directx-11

I'm having trouble rendering a sprite in dx11, I've just started with the basics. Here is my simple shader code:

```
//Shader Model 4.0
//Default shaders for rendering a point sprite

Texture2D DiffuseTexture : register( t0 );

SamplerState DiffuseTextureSampler : register( s0 );

cbuffer cbViewProj : register( b0 )
{
    float3x3 ViewProjection;
}

struct VS_INPUT
{
    float2 Pos : POSITION;
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct PS_INPUT
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD0;
};

PS_INPUT VS( VS_INPUT input )
{
    PS_INPUT output;
    float3 oVec = float3(input.Pos.x, input.Pos.y, 1.0f);   
    oVec = mul(oVec, ViewProjection);

    output.Pos = float4(oVec.x, oVec.y, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    output.Tex = input.Text;

    return output;
}

float4 PS( PS_INPUT input) : SV_Target
{
    return DiffuseTexture.Sample( DiffuseTextureSampler, input.Tex );
}
```

As you can see it has the bare minimum, not even a world matrix to move the sprite yet. My "ViewProjection" matrix is a 2D orthographic matrix. I used this setup with directx9 and everything worked fine.

Moving into dx11 I'm having trouble. I believe there is something wrong with the way I'm setting my ViewProjection matrix or how it is being read in the shader.

First I used PIX to check my vertex buffer / the order the vertices were entering the vertex shader:
[image: BadSprite1]

So that seemed fine. Next I added the viewprojection matrix to project the verticies into screen space, as shown in the shader code I posted. The result...
[image: BadSprite1]

So as you can see, the vertices are not projecting correct. For starters:

- prim0vert0 = prim0vert1
- prim1vert4 = prim1vert5

This doesn't make sense to me since there are different vertex values being processed. You can tell the vertices are entering in the same order as my initial testing by looking at the UV coords.
This is how my 3x3 viewprojection matrix buffer looks:

[image]

I manually wrote over the top what matrix row/column the buffer values correspond with. The three values at the bottom are just padding to ensure my buffer size is in multiples of 16. So... like in directx:

- m00 = matrix row1, column1
- m01 = matrix row1, column2
- etc

The red values on the right represent how my ViewProjection matrix accesses the buffer in the hlsl code.

For some reason it is treating it as a float4x4? Could that be me problem... or am I wayyyy of track in solving my problem

-UPDATE-

I've done a bit of research and am now working under the assumption the float3x3 becomes fragmented when being stored in the registers (as it is packed in groups of 4 floats).

Now it seems even if my application is completely 2D I should still use a 4x4 matrix due to this annoying behavior. Is this correct, or is there some workaround I am unaware of?

Comment: Any chance to see how you send your matrix to the shader? truncation/transpose could be problem.

Comment: Shouldn't `float3x3 ViewProjection` be `matrix ViewProjection`, with the Input position being a float4?

Chances are you're treating the ViewProjection matrix as a 3d-matrix code side, where as this treats it as a 2d-matrix.

Comment: To answer your update, I would always use a 4x4 matrix, even with 2D - I'd try to limit the 'concept' of 2D in your pipeline to the setup of the ortho projection matrix. On a side note, I had a lot of problems moving from FFP to shaders due to pre-transformed vertex formats (using D3DFVF_XYZRHW or D3DDECLUSAGE_POSITIONT), as, as far as I know, the concept of pre-transformed vertices doesn't apply to DX10+. It ends up turning on parts of the FFP in DX9, and thus might make seemingly similar code in DX10/11, act critically different under the hood.

Comment: You may want to take a look at SpriteBatch in [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929).

Answer (score 1):

Modern graphics hardware is designed/optimized to work with 4x4 byte vectors, that's 4 floating point values. Even when you use float3 vector, internally it's still taking up a single register that holds float4.

For vector math to work properly, each point has to start at address that is 16 byte aligned, which is a problem when you have float3xN, cause 2nd point in would start at byte 12

So you have to pad your data to 16 byte alignment. Try using float4x3. Internally, your float3x3 operations will still take up space of float4x3